# Can I get a URL to revision on CodePen

Tags: codepen

Is it possible to get a URL to a specific revision on CodePen?  Or possibly lock a particular pen down from ever being edited?

I ask in particular because if a Pen can be changed, it should probably not be used to demonstrate code on various SE sites (especially S/O).

Comment: The author could update a post without it changing the URL but any forking by subsequent users would change the URL. Are you worried about the original author editing their own work?

Comment: Yes; primarily I'm worried about the original author editing their own work, although I haven't seen a case of it yet.  StackOverflow reminds users pasting JSfiddle links to include code snippets in the question though, which may alleviate the problem a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't link to a specific code version on CodePen.  Any revisions are saved under the same URL.  However, both [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and [repl.it](https://repl.it/) save revisions under separate URLs.